# Use Release.Name in pv.yaml as value of shareName field

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have this pv.yaml file:

```
{{ if .Values.useSystemFilesPV}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mono-pv-{{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: {{ .Values.pvStorage }}
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  azureFile:
    secretName: mono
    secretNamespace: {{ .Release.Name }}
    shareName: mono-sua-tst-man-yv/idit-core-pen
    readOnly: false
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0777
    - file_mode=0777
    - uid=1000
    - gid=1000
    - mfsymlinks
    - nobrl
{{ end }}
```

**And I need to create this folder: idit-core-pen under the existing file share: mono-sua-tst-man-yv.**

Regarding this field: shareName ,the value is mono-sua-tst-man-yv/idit-core-pen ('mono-sua-tst-man-yv' is my file share, and 'idit-core-pen' is a folder inside this file share).
**It works well like that!** it creates the folder idit-core-pen under the existing fileshare.
But when I change the value into: mono-sua-tst-man-yv/{{ .Release.Name }} it doesn't work (it doesnt create the folder under the file share) and it throws this errors message:

```
MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "mono-pv-idit-core-pen" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = volume(#mono#mono-sua-tst-man-yv/idit-core-pen#mono-pv-idit-core-pen#idit-core-pen) mount //euaidtcoretrunkaks.file.core.windows.net/mono-sua-tst-man-yv/idit-core-pen on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/mono-pv-idit-core-pen/globalmount failed with mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: mount Mounting arguments: -t cifs -o dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000,mfsymlinks,nobrl,actimeo=30,<masked> //euaidtcoretrunkaks.file.core.windows.net/mono-sua-tst-man-yv/idit-core-pen /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/mono-pv-idit-core-pen/globalmount Output: mount error(2): No such file or directory Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

I tried to play a bit with the quotation marks  (example: "mono-sua-tst-man-yv/{{ .Release.Name }}" ) and with the curly brackets (example: mono-sua-tst-man-yv/{{`{{ .Release.Name }}`}}) but it didn't help. It didn't create the folder.

Maybe anyone has a better idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the context where you're trying to use the file path?  In most environments there is a persistent volume provisioner that automatically creates PersistentVolumes when it sees PersistentVolumeClaims, do you need to manually create this (cluster-global) object at all?

Comment: Yes. in this example I need to create this folder: idit-core-pen manually under this share file: mono-sua-tst-man-yv , and then it will work..but I want to be able to create this folder: idit-core-pen automatically via the yaml file under the file share (without using CLI commands or another script). Is that possible? or I have to use a script for that? thanks @David Maze

Comment: Nothing at a Kubernetes YAML layer deals with the _contents_ of volumes at all.  You can't write a YAML file that would create a directory in a specific PersistentVolume.

Comment: So what are my options to create a directory under an existing fileshare automatically? I know how to do it from powershell but I'm looking for another solution , thanks